# How can I open the parent app on iPhone from my WatchKit app?

Tags: swift, xcode6, watchkit

I'm trying to open the parent application of my Apple Watch app.

In Xcode Beta 2 we could use this code:

```
WKInterFaceController.openParentApplication
```

However, in Xcode beta 3 I couldn't found that code any longer. Now I don't know how to open the parent application from the watch app. Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Objective-C method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) is:

```
+ (BOOL)openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                    reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo,
                                    NSError *error))reply
```

[The Swift method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) is:

```
class func openParentApplication(_ userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
                    reply reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!,
                                    NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Bool
```

So you need to pass the iPhone application a reply() block in order to have activate it from your WatchKit extension. Here's one way it could be implemented, for instance:

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"executeMethodA"]; // This string is arbitrary, just must match here and at the iPhone side of the implementation.
NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[requestString] forKeys:@[@"theRequestString"]];

[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"\nReply info: %@\nError: %@",replyInfo, error);
   }];
```

Your iPhone application's AppDelegate needs to implement the following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
NSString * request = [userInfo objectForKey:@"requestString"];

if ([request isEqualToString:@"executeMethodA"]) {
    // Do whatever you want to do when sent the message. For instance... 
    [self executeMethodABC];
}

// This is just an example of what you could return. The one requirement is 
// you do have to execute the reply block, even if it is just to 'reply(nil)'.
// All of the objects in the dictionary [must be serializable to a property list file][3].
// If necessary, you can covert other objects to NSData blobs first. 
NSArray * objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myObjectA, myObjectB, myObjectC, nil];
NSArray * keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"objectAName", @"objectBName", @"objectCName", nil];
NSDictionary * replyContent = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

reply(replyContent);
}
```

The WKInterfaceController method openParentApplication:reply: launches the containing app in the background when the iPhone (or iOS Simulator) is unlocked or locked. Note that statements from Apple indicate that the WatchKit extension was always intended to launch your iPhone application in the background, and it was only an implementation detail of the simulator that it appeared to launch your iPhone application in the foreground in previous betas.

If you want to test your WatchKit app and your iPhone app running at the same time, simply launch the WatchKit app from Xcode under the Schemes menu, and then manually launch your iPhone app in the simulator by clicking on its springboard icon.

Comment: i didn't see this function in Xcode 6 beta3. did you check that?

Comment: Hieu, saying "did you check that" to the person answering your question, without checking it yourself, isn't great Stack Overflow practice. Because it's clear you didn't check it: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:

Comment: @DuncanBabbage This answer is wrong. `openParentApplication` won't launch the application on the phone in the foreground, only in the background. You don't answer the original question.

Comment: Nowhere in the original question does it state that the desired outcome is to open the parent application in the foreground. The original post stated that they were using the method openParentApplication, which obviously informed my answer. You will see in my answer it already says: "Note that statements from Apple indicate that the WatchKit extension was always intended to launch your iPhone application in the background, and it was only an implementation detail of the simulator that it appeared to launch your iPhone application in the foreground in previous betas." My answer is not wrong.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for highlighting the point that WatchKit extension is intended to launch the iPhone application in the background. Is there's really no other way to launch the iOS app in foreground from the Apple watch? I'm able to launch an Android app from my galaxy S running Tizen. Thought of implementing the same logic to Apple Watch...

Comment: closing bracket and semicolon missing

  [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"\nReply info: %@\nError: %@",replyInfo, error);
      }];

Answer (score 5):

**If you need to open your parent app in the foreground, use [Handoff](https://developer.apple.com/handoff/)!**

**Example**:

Somewhere shared for both:

```
static let sharedUserActivityType = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.youraction"
static let sharedIdentifierKey = "identifier"
```

on your Watch:

```
updateUserActivity(sharedUserActivityType, userInfo: [sharedIdentifierKey : 123456], webpageURL: nil)
```

on your iPhone in App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool {
    if (userActivityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]!) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if (userActivity.activityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        if let userInfo = userActivity.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let identifier = userInfo[sharedIdentifierKey] as? Int {
                //Do something
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Handoff", message: "Handoff has been triggered for identifier \(identifier)" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Thanks for the info!")
                alert.show()
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**And finally (this step is important!!!): In your Info.plist(s)**

[image]

Comment: can you please provide demo project to open  parent app in the foreground, using Handoff!