# Bring iOS App to Foreground in WatchKit

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

I am developing a WatchKit extension for one of my Apps where I really want to have the iPhone App running in the foreground, since it is doing the heavy lifting and is designed to use location services only when active. I know openParentApplication:reply only opens the App in the background (unless it is already active). What I am currently trying out is using a custom URL scheme for my App, and having the App initially open itself from within the handleWatchKitExtension code in the App Delegate. This works perfectly in the Simulator. Unfortunately I did not have this approach ready when I tested my App on real Apple Watches. Does anyone see a problem with this approach to bring the iPhone App to the foreground from the Apple Watch?

Comment: See my detailed answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28823756/1342462). You cannot do this according to Apple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch iOS App from Apple Watch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760986/how-to-launch-ios-app-from-apple-watch)

Comment: I can confirm, this does not work on a real watch. If you try, your app will get rejected. In short, the reason is that `openURL` cannot be called from a background state and since openParent, opens your app in background mode, it cannot call `openURL`.  Yes, it does work in the simulator but not in real hardware.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, apps can't bring themselves to the foreground. The best thing you can do is to post a local notification (`UILocalNotification`, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) and invite the user to bring your app to the foreground.

But for your use case, why not just have your phone app use location services in the background?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW1) states that the app on the iPhone will run in the background if it was not active before.