# Launching the parent application from the watch app

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos-3, watchos-4

How can I launch the parent application in background mode on the iPhone directly from the watch?

On Endomondo watch app when you press "start", the parent application will launch itself in the background on the iPhone and start sending data (such as gps location) to the watch. The watch app cannot run without connection with the parent application.

I read about openParentApplication which apparently launched the parent app in the background, but it seemed to only be for watchOS 1 and now we should use Watch Connectivity instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch iOS App from Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760986/how-to-launch-ios-app-from-apple-watch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use WatchConnectivity WCSession->sendMessage

Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background and makes it reachable.

[offical doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage)

Comment: Does this mean that the sent message will reach the phone even when it wasn't in the background or foreground?

Comment: the sentence I highlighted from the official doc says "YES"