# How can I open the application on iPhone from my WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am using watchkit in my application. I want to open application in iphone through watchkit.I have searched a lot but couldn’t find anything. Any help would be appreceated.

i also tried below link
[How can I open the parent app on iPhone from my WatchKit app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884123/how-can-i-open-the-parent-app-on-iphone-from-my-watchkit-app/29448975#29448975)

Comment: did you check this tutorial? https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchkit-open-ios-app-from-watch/

Comment: The tutorial link that you provided is very straightforward, what problem do you have?

Answer (score 4):

If you are work with Objective C then just put the following method in `AppDelegate.m` File.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
    NSString * request = [userInfo objectForKey:@"requestString"];
    if ([request isEqualToString:@"executeMethodA"]) {
        // Do whatever you want to do when sent the message. For instance...
        //[self executeMethodABC];
    }
    reply(@{@"clicked from  watch":@(1)});
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Implementing the method**

> You should implement the receiving message method
>   (`application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply`) in your
>   AppDelegate file.

**Swift: AppDelegate.swift**

```
let message = userInfo.objectForKey("message") as! NSString
if message.isEqualToString("launchApp") {
    //Launch functions here
}
```

**Objective-C: AppDelegate.m**

```
NSString* message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"message"];
if ([message isEqualToString:@"launchApp"]) {
    // Launch functions here
}
```

**Conclusion**

1- You should implement the receiving message method in your App Delegate.

2- In Swift, the app delegate is `AppDelegate.swift`.

3- In Obj-C, the app delegate is `AppDelegate.m`.

4- The receiving message method is `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply`.